# How to install Dirac (a Chrome DevTools fork for ClojureScript) on macOS Monterey 12.5 if error: "Could not locate clojure/data/ files" appears?

Tags: macos, installation, google-chrome-devtools, clojurescript

I am trying to install [Dirac](https://github.com/binaryage/dirac) on a Macbook Air M1 running Monterey 12.5.

I am following the [documentation](https://github.com/binaryage/dirac) which indicates:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/binaryage/dirac/master/install > /tmp/dirac.install && sudo bash /tmp/dirac.install
```

The installation seems to have worked out since it exists on binaries:

```
   Pedros-MacBook-Air:bin pedro$ pwd
   /usr/local/bin

   Pedros-MacBook-Air:bin pedro$ ls -1
   dirac
   lein
```

Unfortunately, when I go to the 2nd step on manual which is running `dirac`, the error below is retrieved:

```
   Pedros-MacBook-Air:bin pedro$ dirac
   WARNING: update-vals already refers to: #'clojure.core/update-vals in namespace: clojure.tools.analyzer.utils, being replaced by: #'clojure.tools.analyzer.utils/update-vals
   WARNING: update-keys already refers to: #'clojure.core/update-keys in namespace: clojure.tools.analyzer.utils, being replaced by: #'clojure.tools.analyzer.utils/update-keys
   WARNING: update-vals already refers to: #'clojure.core/update-vals in namespace: clojure.tools.analyzer, being replaced by: #'clojure.tools.analyzer.utils/update-vals
   WARNING: update-keys already refers to: #'clojure.core/update-keys in namespace: clojure.tools.analyzer, being replaced by: #'clojure.tools.analyzer.utils/update-keys
   WARNING: update-vals already refers to: #'clojure.core/update-vals in namespace: clojure.tools.analyzer.passes, being replaced by: #'clojure.tools.analyzer.utils/update-vals
   WARNING: update-vals already refers to: #'clojure.core/update-vals in namespace: clojure.tools.analyzer.passes.uniquify, being replaced by: #'clojure.tools.analyzer.utils/update-vals
   Execution error (FileNotFoundException) at dirac.nrepl.compilation.direct/eval15283$loading (direct.clj:1).
   Could not locate clojure/data/json__init.class, clojure/data/json.clj or clojure/data/json.cljc on classpath.

Full report at:
/var/folders/fh/7d_1drwd2ps3zw03j9ftkqs80000gn/T/clojure-1010884132545121253.edn
```

Initially, I tried running it at `home` folder. I thought it would work out fine.

Then, I decided to run it inside a project folder that had the file `clojure/data/json.clj`
included in the the `project.clj` file. Unfortunately, even this approach **did not** work out.

Below you see a simplified version of the `project.clj` file:

```lisp
(defproject abcd    ; Should be copied from shadow-cljs.edn
  :description "xxxx"
  :url "xxxx"

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.9.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.339"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "RELEASE"]
                 [binaryage/devtools ~devtools-version]
                 [binaryage/dirac ~dirac-version]
                 [org.clojure/data.json "2.4.0"]
                 [figwheel ~figwheel-version]
                 ;; Selmer for templating of .json config files
                 [selmer "1.12.50"]]

... (omitted content because it seems irrelevant) ...

  :profiles {:repl
             {:repl-options {:port             8230
                             :nrepl-middleware [dirac.nrepl/middleware]
                             :init             (do
                                                 (require 'dirac.agent)
                                                 (dirac.agent/boot!))


}}})
```

1 - I thought Dirac would work out even outside of the project folder. Is it necessary to be in the project folder?

2 - Why is Dirac complaining about the Json library even though it is listed as a dependency?
Is there any difference between `clojure/data/json.clj` (error message retrieved) and `org.clojure/data.json` (my dependency)?

Comment: Seems like it's trying to use the `clojure.data.json` library but it's not there. You can add it yourself to your dependencies: https://github.com/clojure/data.json

Comment: In macOS, where are my Clojure dependencies? What is the path?

Comment: You specify them in your project, usually via `deps.edn` or `project.clj`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, @EugenePakhomov. Unfortunately, even after adding it to the `project.clj` file, it does not work. I will update my question with this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've received a workaround on [dirac/issues/98](https://github.com/binaryage/dirac/issues/98):  adding `{:deps {org.clojure/data.json {:mvn/version "2.4.0"}}}` to ~/.clojure/deps.edn.

The local launcher script has a dependency on the release version of ClojureScript, that no longer includes clojure/data.json. A better workaround is changing the /usr/local/bin/dirac file [line 119](https://github.com/binaryage/dirac/blob/34064db1ff668938a22136fedd1f5077bb2504b9/dirac#L119) by adding clojure.data.json there as well (or pinning to a ClojureScript version before 1.11.51):

```bash
DEPS="{:deps {\
  $DIRAC_CLI_DEPS_COORDINATE \
  org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version \"RELEASE\"} \
  org.clojure/data.json {:mvn/version \"2.4.0\"} \ 
  clj-logging-config/clj-logging-config {:mvn/version \"1.9.12\"} \
}}"
```

### Explanation

The dependency org.clojure/data.json was removed from ClojureScript in version 1.11.51 of May 13th 2022. See [release notes](https://clojurescript.org/news/2022-05-13-release#_vendorization_of_tools_reader_data_json_and_transit_clj):

> **Vendorization of tools.reader, data.json, and transit-clj**
>  (...)
>  After conferring with the Clojure Team, we decided to vendorize all these dependencies. This way we can AOT everything and be confident that we won’t create a conflict that can’t easily be fixed via normal dependency management. (...) The dependance on data.json has been removed.

Comment: Do you mean `usr/local/bin/dirac`?

Comment: This was the previous `DEPS`: `DEPS="{:deps {\
  $DIRAC_CLI_DEPS_COORDINATE \
  org.clojure/clojurescript {:mvn/version \"RELEASE\"} \
  clj-logging-config/clj-logging-config {:mvn/version \"1.9.12\"} \
}}"`. I will change it to your suggestion.

Comment: I believe the installation was somewhat succesfull. However, I can't finish the quickstart guide, yet. Please, see this here: https://github.com/binaryage/dirac/issues/100

Comment: I still cannot run Dirac and insert ClojureScript on the browser console. But, your answer apparently helped to solve the problem initially discussed. Thus, I believe it is worth the bounty!